# Magento 2 change Street Address label

Tags: checkout, shipping-address

I want something like this
[image]

I tried looking into vendor/magento.../i8n translation file, but the field street address is not there.

How can I rename this specific field?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to override en_US.csv file into your theme i18n folder.

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Comment: "Street Address" field is not in this file, if I have to add it there, how do I do it exactly?

Comment: have you tried turning on the inline translator if this this didnt work

Comment: Hi dava, there is no i18n/en_US.csv file in my theme

Comment: if there isnt one simply create it